# Counting records in sql statement fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1, s.* 
FROM quiz.score s 
WHERE id BETWEEN @a - @l1 AND @a + @l2 order by points desc;
```

`@i:=@i+1` shoult increment with each row but I get for each record `NULL`.

I dont see the problem.
Could you help me?

Comment: you need to initialize @i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any user-defined variable, @i has an initial value of NULL at the start of your session, and then NULL + 1 always yields NULL.  **NULL is not 0.**

You should initialize @i := 0 before it starts counting.

You can do this in a separate statement:

```
SET @i:=0;

SELECT @i:=@i+1, s.* 
FROM quiz.score s 
WHERE id BETWEEN @a - @l1 AND @a + @l2 order by points desc;
```

Or another trick some people do is to write a subquery to do it:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1, s.* 
FROM (SELECT @i:=0) AS _init
JOIN quiz.score s 
WHERE id BETWEEN @a - @l1 AND @a + @l2 order by points desc;
```

One final way you could resolve the initial case is to default @i to 0 with COALESCE():

```
SELECT @i:=COALESCE(@i,0)+1, s.* 
FROM quiz.score s 
WHERE id BETWEEN @a - @l1 AND @a + @l2 order by points desc;
```

The COALESCE() function returns its first argument that is not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting @i,
So by default @i is NULL
and any value + NULL = NULL
try

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT @i:=@i+1, s.* 
FROM quiz.score s 
WHERE id BETWEEN @a - @l1 AND @a + @l2 order by points desc;
```